# Balance of forces in a mechanics problem

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-analysis, classical-mechanics

I tried to solve a particular problem of mechanics and found some difficulties in the vector analysis part that I can't get rid of. It's probably some stupid mistake I made, but I can't see it now, and it doesn't appear something very obvious. I think it probably has something to do with complex numbers, but I couldn't find any that generates a negative root.

[image]
[image]

The problem appears at (2), because in ordinary cases the module of a vector is always positive. I.e, if $U=0\hat{i}+0\hat{j}+n\hat{k}$ is a vector, then it's module is $((U))=\sqrt[]{0^2+0^2+n^2}=\sqrt[]{n^2}$, which is positive since the power vanishes any negative sign. Now, $$\sqrt[]{n^2}<0 \Rightarrow n^2<0^2\Rightarrow n<0$$ since the product of two negative numbers is positive, we have $n.n>0$, a contradiction, since $n^2<0$. Anyway, does that mean the module of the vector is a complex number? If it does, why I found a negative one without imaginary parts or something. I know that people usually put negative modules to represent the direction of the force, i.e, $-6KN$ would mean the force contrary to the positive side with magnitude $6KN$; but that's just an abuse of language whose purpose is already done by the unities, modules having nothing to with it. In this case, we would have $6(-\hat{i})$.

Resuming the opera: if $$N_B=-80KN \Rightarrow ((N_B\hat{k}))=\sqrt[]{(-80)^2}=-80=\sqrt[]{(-80)(-80)}=\sqrt[]{80.80}=\sqrt[]{6400}$$
Any help is appreciated. Have a nice day.

P.S.: Sorry about the picture, I turned it on windows but it didn't do any good when I uploaded to SE.

Comment: The modulus (not module) of a vector is always positive, even when the components are complex, so you are correct you already have made a mistake.

Comment: Where are you getting $n^2<0$? You have $\sqrt{n^2}>0$ and $n^2>0$.

Comment: @Ian, while working with implications, material or formal, we work with conditionals; the hypothesis is readed together with "if.." and the conective "then" and the protasis. So, that propositions is read "IF the square root of $n^2$, then..".

Comment: @Ricardo That doesn't even make sense as phrased, "the square root of $n^2$ isn't a proposition. You also never had a statement "if $\sqrt{n^2} < 0$ then ...". At any rate, I assume that $N_B$ is the modulus that you want to not be negative? If so, then you have probably just drawn your figure with the corresponding vector pointing in the wrong direction. In other words with $+4 N_B k$, the modulus is $4 |N_B|$ and $N_B < 0$.

Comment: @Ian I started with an hypothesis and showed it could'nt hold. Anything that implies anything is a proposition, you should read Russell https://archive.org/details/principlesofmath005807mbp.

Comment: @Ian I understand what you mean, but $((4N_B \hat{k}))$ without sign, since $+4N_B$ is a relation whose field is $Ncfin$ while $4N_B$ is a cardinal, is just $\sqrt[]{(4N_B)^2}=\sqrt[]{4^2.(N_B)^2}$ which is "positive", i.e, cardinal without sign. There's no way we ever get a signed "number" (since they're not numbers at all) perfoming operations with cardinals.

Comment: @Ian You can see that in https://archive.org/stream/PrincipiaMathematicaVol2/AlfredNorthWhiteheadBertrandRussell-PrincipiaMathematicaVol2#page/n484/mode/1up and https://archive.org/stream/PrincipiaMathematicaVolumeIii/WhiteheadRussell-PrincipiaMathematicaVolumeIii#page/n241/mode/2up. Sorry the message got to long..